# How do I get the words I copied yesterday in ubuntu

Tags: copy, copy-and-paste

I use copyQ to capture the words I copy and paste into ubuntu, but I'm trying to find a word I copied and pasted yesterday but I can't find it in the copyQ interface, is there a way to capture everything I copied and pasted yesterday?

Comment: From where and to where did you copy it? Did you edit local files or did you work in an internet browser? I have not read about any long time storage or general logging of copied and pasted words between application programs. If it is important to remember what you change, you should keep old versions of files (documents, source code, etc), and also backup copies in another drive (because a drive can fail or get lost/stolen without a warning).

Comment: Internet browser(google chrome)

Comment: I seldom use Chrome, only in my phone (I use Firefox in my computer). I know that browsers are good at remembering previous websites that have been visited, but I don't think that they save copied and pasted words (or text strings), that were copied between different edit boxes.  As a matter of fact I think many people would be upset, and consider saving words like that spying, similar to keylogging. Let us hope that someone else knows more about what is saved in Chrome and in copyQ and can help you.

Comment: CopyQ must have configuration options that allow you to determine how many copies are kept. Clipboard managers keep a limited number of entries only.